# Why have some of my Pokecoins disappeared?

Tags: pokemon-go

I purchased 1200 Pokecoins which showed up in the game.  Later I discovered they were down to 880, without me ever authorizing any purchases.  What is going on?

Comment: Did you never make any purchases at all?

Comment: If I did, it wasn't apparent to me! Given the choices in the store I would have had to make 4 individual purchases of single items.  Could I have been that clumsy? Or was the UI misbehaving? I do see 6 incense items, but I don't know how I got them.  I visited a number of Poke Stops.  I just know I didn't buy them voluntarily.

Comment: There's a bug (possibly only on Android) where a purchase sometimes gets duplicated when you make it and too many coins get spent (resulting in purchasing extra items).

Answer (score 7):

If you go into the Help Center in the app (Main PokéBall icon : Settings : Help Center), click the "Submit a Request" button in the upper right corner and one of the choices there is "Help with PokéCoins and premium items". That will let you send an e-mail to Niantic about the problem. Report the same thing that you said here. (It's also highly advisable to read the various general and specific FAQ/help entries you'll pass along the way, in case any of them are applicable.)

In theory they may be able to check the logs of shop transactions for your account and figure out what happened. In practice, given that they've really got their hands full with this game, they might just replace the missing coins to make the problem go away.

Comment: Thanks.  I did as you suggested.  They replied that they will follow up in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe that you had your phone on another account or you may have accidentally hit something. It is most likely that your account was on someone else's phone and they used 400 of your Poke Coins. I am sorry for your loss of Poke Coins and if that wasn't the case report it to Niatic